# How can I append one list to another where Indices match in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists :

```
List1 = [['ab' , 'bc' ] , ['ef' , 'ij' ]] 
List2 = [['pq' , 'rs' ] , ['uv' , 'xy' ]]
```

I want a list that looks like this:

```
FinalList = [['ab', 'bc', 'pq', 'rs'], ['ef', 'ij', 'uv', 'xy']]
```

Elements in the first position of List1 must be appended to elements in first position of list 2 , elements in second position of list 1 must be appended to elements in second position of list 2 and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: But the following answers require the same length of the list

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension the zipped lists.

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Comment: Good answer. Its just that the lack of spaces around the `+` and after `,` that are bugging me. :P **Update:** You now have my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple comprehension that will work so long as the two lists are the same size

```
a = [ ['ab' , 'bc' ] , ['ef' , 'ij' ] ]
b = [ ['pq' , 'rs' ] , ['uv' , 'xy' ] ]
blended = [[a[ix]+b[ix]] for ix in range(len(a))]
```

Results in

```
[['ab', 'bc', 'pq', 'rs']], [['ef', 'ij', 'uv', 'xy']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code too,

```
List1 = [['ab' , 'bc' ] , ['ef' , 'ij' ]] 
List2 = [['pq' , 'rs' ] , ['uv' , 'xy' ]]

Finallist = [List1[0]+List2[0]]+[List1[1]+List2[1]]
```